# Dash / Plotly bar chart shows two bars on top of each other, effectively displaying twice the real value

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a problem with the dash app. From 2018 onwards it shows two bars stacked on top of each other (showing 110 visually). The value when hovering, however, is still the correct one ( around 55 and decreasing).

**You can find the code on the bottom.**

Also, when I plot with matplotlib.pyplot the graph shows correctly.

In addition, the fine line between the bars (around a value of 55) shows the correct value. This is where the second bar is stacked.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem or knows how to solve this? 
The stacked bar should disappear so that the correct value of around 55 is displayed.

[image: Graph with double values from 2018 onwards, enlarged]
[image: Graph with double values from 2018 onwards]
[image: Pyplot graph for comparison]

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'path')
import pandas as pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import forex_factory_calendar_scraper as ffcs
import economic_calendar_reader as ecr 
import time


#  Fuctions for RangeSlider. Dash does not support DateTime objects
def unixTimeMillis(dt):
    ''' Convert datetime to unix timestamp '''
    return int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))

def unixToDatetime(unix):
    ''' Convert unix timestamp to datetime. '''
    return pd.to_datetime(unix,unit='s')

def getMarks(start, end, daterange, Nth=50000):
    ''' Returns the marks for labeling. 
        Every Nth value will be used.
    '''
    result = {}
    for i, date in enumerate(daterange):
        if(i%Nth == 1):
            # Append value to dict
            result[unixTimeMillis(date)] = str(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    return result



app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#  Importing data
ffcs.get_economic_calendar("calendar.php?month=dec.2019","calendar.php?month=dec.2019")
calendar = ecr.read_economic_calendar()

#calendar = calendar.loc[calendar.Currency == 'EUR']
available_currencies = calendar.Currency.unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='currency1',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_currencies],
                value='EUR'
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='currency2',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_currencies],
                value='USD'
            )
        ],style={'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='events1',

            )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='events2',

            )
        ],style={'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='disp_col1',
                options=[
                {'label': 'Actual', 'value':'Actual'},
                {'label': 'Surprise %', 'value':'Surprise_Pct'}
                ],
                value='Actual'
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='disp_col2',
                options=[
                {'label': 'Actual', 'value':'Actual'},
                {'label': 'Surprise %', 'value':'Surprise_Pct'}
                ],
                value='Actual'
            )
        ],style={'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    ]),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='surprice_pct-ts1'),
    ],style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='surprice_pct-ts2'),
    ],style={'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.RangeSlider(
                id='year_slider',
                min = unixTimeMillis(calendar.Date.min()),
                max = unixTimeMillis(calendar.Date.max()),
                value = [unixTimeMillis(calendar.Date.min()),
                         unixTimeMillis(calendar.Date.max())]
                #marks=getMarks(calendar.Date.min(),
                #            calendar.Date.max(), calendar.Date)
            )
        ],style={'width': '70%', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ],style={'width': '100%', 'text-align': 'center'})
])

#   Left Graph ------------------------------------------------------------->>
@app.callback(
     dash.dependencies.Output('surprice_pct-ts1', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency1', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('events1', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('disp_col1', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('year_slider', 'value')])

def update_ts1(currency1,events1, disp_col1, year_slider):

    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency1]
    output = output[output.Event == events1]


    data = []
    trace_data = go.Bar(x=list(output.Date),
                        y=list(output[disp_col1]))

    data.append(trace_data)
    layout = {'title':'Economic Indicators - {} - {}'.format(currency1,disp_col1)}

    return {
        'data':data,
        'layout': layout
    }

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('events1', 'options'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency1', 'value')])
def update_evets1(currency1):
    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency1]
    available_events1 = output.Event.unique()
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_events1]

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('events1', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency1', 'value')])
def update_evets1(currency1):
    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency1]
    available_events1 = output.Event.unique()
    return available_events1[0]


#   Right Graph ------------------------------------------------------------->>
@app.callback(
     dash.dependencies.Output('surprice_pct-ts2', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency2', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('events2', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('disp_col2', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('year_slider', 'value')])

def update_ts1(currency2,events2, disp_col2, year_slider):

    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency2]
    output = output[output.Event == events2]


    data = []
    trace_data = go.Bar(x=list(output.Date),
                        y=list(output[disp_col2]))

    data.append(trace_data)
    layout = {'title':'Economic Indicators - {} - {}'.format(currency2,disp_col2)}

    return {
        'data':data,
        'layout': layout
    }

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('events2', 'options'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency2', 'value')])
def update_evets1(currency2):
    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency2]
    available_events2 = output.Event.unique()
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_events2]

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('events2', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency2', 'value')])
def update_evets1(currency2):
    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency2]
    available_events2 = output.Event.unique()
    return available_events2[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: You'll need to share your code so we can see how you're creating these charts. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: Please also rephrase you question as it is totally unclear what is your problem and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the title and included the dash app.